getting error when scheduled refresh reports in power bi
There are some reports in power bi report server. Each of these reports has scheduled refresh times. However, some reports give a memory error error during scheduled refresh. Delays occur in the work because the data power bi report is not updated. I should note that the refresh times of reports with the same data sources are not the same.Most of the datasets are created from tables in sql What can be done to prevent this error from occurring? i can
When I encounter a memory error in the sheduled refresh time  I have to edit the report and manually refresh the tables one by one. Doing so takes a lot of time.

Can you provide some more details, data sources, run times, examples anything more you can add, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Sorry but i can not share datasources.I can say  datasets come from sql baza to power bi .In the normal process run time  must bi 15 -20 minute .But wait hours and end of auto refresh i get error like memory error

When your report calls an sql database, i've discovered that power bi opens a lot of sessions that are persistent. One of the solutions is to increase the number of sessions allowed by your database. The other solution is to develop an api that will act as an interface between the database and power bi.

My data sources come from oracle sql to power bi.How can I do as you mentioned.Can ou explain please

@Narin can you share the error message ?

ERROR-There's not enough memory to complete this operation. Please try again later when there may be more memory available.
In memory everythin is ok .State of memory is 67\136
İ cant find what is a problem
